# mongodb auditing in spring boot for saving createdDate, lastModifiedDate, createdBy, lastModifiedBy

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven

I am using spring boot, therefore I am not using any xml files for configurations. 
What I have to do is to EnableMongoAuditing for saving createdDate, lastModifiedDate etc while saving data using MongoRepositories.

My model class

```
@Component
@Document(collection = "CAPPING")
public class TemporaryCapping extends BaseEntity {

    @Field("contract_id")
    private BigInteger contractId;

    @Field("period_id")
    private BigInteger periodId;

    @Field("user_id")
    private BigInteger userId;

    @Field("amount")
    private Double amount;

    @Field("type_of_capping")
    private TypeOfCapping typeOfCapping;

    public BigInteger getContractId() {
        return contractId;
    }

    public void setContractId(BigInteger contractId) {
        this.contractId = contractId;
    }

    public BigInteger getPeriodId() {
        return periodId;
    }

    public void setPeriodId(BigInteger periodId) {
        this.periodId = periodId;
    }

    public BigInteger getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(BigInteger userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public TypeOfCapping getTypeOfCapping() {
        return typeOfCapping;
    }

    public void setTypeOfCapping(TypeOfCapping typeOfCapping) {
        this.typeOfCapping = typeOfCapping;
    }


}



public class BaseEntity implements Serializable{

@Id
@Indexed(unique = true)
private BigInteger id;

@CreatedDate
private DateTime createdDate;

@Field("modified_date")
private BigInteger modifiedDate;

public BigInteger getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(BigInteger id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public DateTime getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
}

public void setCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
}

public BigInteger getModifiedDate() {
    return modifiedDate;
}

public void setModifiedDate(BigInteger modifiedDate) {
    this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
}
```

I have used @CreateDate annotation for saving createDate. 
and I have used jodatime dependency for DateTime

```
<dependency>
<groupId>joda-time</groupId>
<artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
<version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

spring-data-mongodb is also added in the dependencies.

This is my main application class

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableMongoAuditing
   public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }

}
```

Where I am wrong in this impelmentation as the date is not getting saved in database? 
Also I know that for saving @createdBy you need to write AuditorAware bean but for now I am just trying to save createdBy.

Where should @EnableMongoAuditing be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my application I configure through Java code. I use @EnableMongAuditing this way and also create convertes for ZonedDateTime.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = { BASE_PACKAGE })
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    public static final String BASE_PACKAGE = "package.with.aggregates";

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
    private String mongoUri;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String databaseName;

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName;
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(mongoUri));
    }

    // Here you must add converters to Joda datetypes. In my solution is ZonedDateTime
    @Override
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<>();
        converterList.add(new DateToZonedDateTimeConverter());
        converterList.add(new ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter());
        return new CustomConversions(converterList);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return BASE_PACKAGE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does the MongoConfiguration class is used?

Comment: The annotation @Configuration says that the class is configration similar as XML but in Java code. You can have many configuration classes just put packageScan to package there configuration classes are.

Comment: How to add a package scan to Spring boot app. @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.some.package"})

Comment: If  add a MongoConfiguration class like this My application is not getting started. and giving exception of org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException for the main class that is EsourceApplication

Comment: When I am trying to connect to mongodb using this configuration class , the connection is not getting established.

Comment: Does the class inicialized? Is package to aggregates right? There is nothing tricky It must work.

Comment: MongoConfiguration class is working and connects to mongodb. Also @LastModifiedDate annotation is working and saving date in db but CreatedDate annotation is not working.

Comment: When @LastModufiedDate works the creating data should work too. Try to check datetype, setters etc. When my all answers somehow help you I would appreciate vote. Thanks.

Comment: If I am not wrong the _id should be null for saving createdDate. If this is true, that is the problem. I am generating id before saving the entity as MongoDB does not have any method for auto generating.

Comment: This has been solved. I did two things 1) Removed the id that I was generatimg using some sequence. and Used Mongodbs ObjectId  2) I did make changes in the Entity but that was not being reflected since It was already created. So I deleted the Entity(dropped the collection in mongodb) and then started the application.

Answer (score 0):

@EnableMongoAuditing can actually be placed anywhere in configurations (next to @Configuration annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution if   `@CreatedDate or @LastModifiedDate` not work as expected (it was not working for me at all).

1. Add unified class for audit, that then you'll extend in any entity (document):

> ```
> @Data
> public abstract class AuditableDates {
>
>   @CreatedDate
>   Instant createdDate;
>
>   @LastModifiedDate
>   Instant updatedDate;
> }
> ```

2. Add config, to notify Spring auditable enabled

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableMongoAuditing
> public class DbConfig {
> }
> ```

3. Extend our Audiable interface - success, on create/edit you'll have expected data in DB.

> ```
> public class User extends AuditableDates {
> ```

In case you use Joda time (or any other specific type), additional CustomConversions should be added.